# Bootstrap Carousel Not Responding (Jquery placed correctly)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently facing issues in regards to Bootstrap's carousel not responding the navigation buttons being pressed. The majority of my search answers was that Jquery was not correctly BEFORE the Bootstrap CDN. I have tried even copy-pasting other snippets of code from answers and the navigation button still does not respond correctly to clicks.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><!--title--></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

Only the first image loads correctly, and the carousel seems to be "frozen."

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7dv1wm1w/

Comment: The fiddle doesn't include bootstrap.js. Working on Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/HGRtuWp3QS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not included the bootstrap.min.js

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript></script>`

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yogesh214/7dv1wm1w/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was oblivious to the fact that the bootstrap link that I had was the stylesheet(.css) and not the actual JS file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see Bootstrap's Javascript file, so that's your answer, why the carousel doesn't work.

On the [getbootstrap.com](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) you can find all the needed files. These which you always need are CSS and JS. Otherwise Bootstrap won't work.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```